# Text under"aria-label" is read twice in VoiceOver Safari browser

Tags: ipad, safari, voiceover, uiaccessibility

I have used "aria-label" for a button . Voice over in Ipad Safari browser reads the text twice. What can be done to fix this? "aria-label" reads only once in MacBook voiceover safari browser.

Answer (score 0):

Check accessibilityLabel and accessibilityHint, they may be the same.
After WWDC2019 Accessibility Inspector Tool was added (Xcode > Open Developer Tool > Accessibility Inspector). 
[(screenshot of Accessibility Inspector window)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Iqm4.png)